# Faster jquery sortable with big data

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui-sortable

Do you have any advice to make "faster jquery sortable"  for the following demo code?

Html Excel Sheet with jquery sortable items demo > http://jsfiddle.net/syy1wmvn/2/

I meant
firstly: sortable element comes to cursor position after 1-2 seconds when you start to drag it . 
secondly: performance for  $("...").sortable({...});

structure:

```
<ul> <!--Days (a Month)-->

  <li> <!--Day1-->
    <ul> <!--Activities  (Sortable) -->
      <li>Activity 1</li>
      <li>Activity 2</li>
    </ul> <!-- Activities -->
  </li> <!--Day1-->


  <li> <!--Day2-->
    <ul> <!-- Activities  (Sortable) -->
      <li>Activity 3</li>
      <li>Activity n</li>
    </ul> <!-- Activities  -->
  </li> <!--Day2-->

</ul>
```

Comment: what do you mean by faster? the user's hand can only go so fast, and the script is fast enough for that...

Comment: i meant 

firstly:   sortable element comes to cursor position after 1-2 seconds when you  start to drag it .  

secondly: performance for  $("...").sortable({...});

Comment: fwiw, it works fine for me. you do have 5000 elements, which is pushing the acceptable number, especially for moving and partially-transparent parts.

Comment: ..."sortable("option", "connectWith", '.ul-activity')"  is main reason for the slowness. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @dandavis  this solution is faster (load and dragging) but i can't drag on empty ul. do you have a idea?  http://jsfiddle.net/008favda/